# how to make square in my tab a different color when active

Tags: javascript, tabs

I added tabs to my page to change content when clicked but what I need is for the square above the tab title to change color on hover and when active.  I have it working for hover but I can't get it to work when that tab is active.  I have tried a:active and a.active and neither have worked.  I'm a beginner with javascript so I don't know if it needs to be added there.

Here is the page - http://pt6-dev.info/donate-now/

Thank you in advanced for any help!! Peggy

Comment: add `.active { color:red; } ` to your css , `a.active` targets the links, the elements with the class `active` are `divs`

Comment: Are you saying I should add it to the tab div?

Comment: no, i'm saying add `.active { color:red; }` to your `css`

Comment: when I do that it makes the whole tab that background color not the little box.

Comment: Please add your code here. Also have a look at this SO guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Side note - it is generally not a great idea to put an interactive element within an interactive element. `<button>` and `<a>` are interactive content and most (if not all) of the interactive content must not have interactive content within it. This is also what is causing your page to refresh whenever a tab is clicked. `:hover` works on any element nowadays, not only `<a>`, so you can change it to `<span>` or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should color the a inside the active class.
Add this to your css:

.tab li .active a {background: #72bda4;}

Comment: @Peggy - please, make sure you mark the (most helpful) answer as the accepted answer. Besides increasing the reputation of the answerer, it also makes the answer highlighted a bit and readers are usually looking for highlighted answers because they are usually the correct ones.